# HTML using 'em' for border-width won't work on Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, width, font-size

I'm trying to use 'em' for sizing all my HTML elements, including the border for divs and imgs.
But when I use css: `border: .1em #000000 solid;` on one of my divs, It won't show in Google chrome but in Firefox and IE. Am I using it in the wrong way? or it's one of Chrome's bugs?
In anyway, how may I fix it? or is there any other way to work around it?

Comment: Seems to be working fine on Chrome 17.0.963.79

Comment: css3 pie *may* help render it consistently in all browsers:- http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `0.1em` computes to a value that is less than `1px`, it may be ignored depending on how the browser chooses to round values. Perhaps it's the case that Firefox and IE round numbers, whereas Chrome floors them. You should probably just use a value of `1px` instead of using `em` for absolutely everything.

Comment: I thought by default 1em is 16px, which .1 em will be computes to 1.6px, then it would be either 2px or 1px after rounding, right?

Comment: Never mind, I accidentally zoomed out the browser, it works now. So as you sad, chrome floors it. Thank you for your answer